# How can I detect device browser closed?

Tags: android, browser

I want to detect when the device browser is being closed.

Is there a broadcast intent or an event to listen for that will notify me when the browser is closed?

Comment: Things don't really get "closed" -- they just are no longer the currently running Activity. They may get closed eventually, but probably not the way you're wanting.

Comment: What do you mean?  The browser activity being terminated by the OS, or the user navigating away from the activity, or what?  The browser generally doesn't *close* in Android, it just moves down the app stack until it's freed by the OS at some later point.

Comment: I want when my android device or emulator browser closed.That is nothing to do with any activity closed.i just want to detect when browser will be closed.

Comment: The browser is an Activity like anything else.

Comment: oh sorry i didnot know that.Do you have any idea how can i detect when browser will be closed ?

Comment: That's what we were asking. Do you want to know when the task has actually ended, or when the browser is not longer the currently running Activity? A user may hit the back or home button to "exit" the browser, but the OS might decide to keep it running until some future time before it **actually** closes it.

Comment: yes i want when when the browser is not longer the currently running Activity.When uset hit back button or home button to "exit" browser.

Comment: Guys whatever you asked i told you, now give me solution.

Comment: I don't think that's the way things work.

Comment: @BrianDupuis i did not get you ? i just wanted to trigger in my activity when browser will be closed.that' it ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is possible. The only possibility to see that current activity has changed the state is to put a broadcast intent into the onPause method of the browser activity. But as I understand the browser is not yours application.

The second possibility if your activity is called with startActivityForResult method. Then when called (active) activity is closed it returns a result. This can be detected in the calling activity. But also I do not think that this is your case.

Can you explain why do you need to detect when a browser is closed?